# sending out input events to windows

Tags: c++, usb, driver

I am attempting to make a joystick driver via [hidapi](http://www.signal11.us/oss/hidapi/);  I would like to know how to send events to the os of any joystick activity.

Comment: Did you read the page you linked??

Comment: Your OS will have a USB HID driver that reads events from the joystick, so you don't need to send the events to the OS.  Do you mean that you are trying to read the joystick events from the joystick and use it in your software application?  You found HIDAPI, so that's a good step; have you tried using it yet?

Comment: I'm trying to use HIDAPI to read from my joystick and send it to a specific application(s). so, I don't have to use motionjoy

Answer (score 0):

That all depends on your OS, as drivers are platform specific. Some IDEs like Visual Studio (Windows) provide templates for drivers which you can use, and a great deal of [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/hh706187(v=vs.85).aspx) about doing so.